# Selective HTML rendering heuristics for crawler

Tags: html, c++, qt, qtwebkit

I use C++, obsolete Qt web kit 5.5.1 (in order to support Windows XP) in a crawler. I use HTML rendering in order to get html/text content. But I'd like to minimize rendering frequency and skip downloading irrelevant stuff in order to speedup crawling.

First of all, I use `QNetworkAccessManager` to get web page, then I pass it via `setContent()` method to `QWebFrame` instance (I consider redirects manually).  I also have  `QNetworkAccessManager` descendant, which can be used to skip certain GET requests.

1. What web page attributes will definitely say that no rendering is required for simple text extraction?
2. What GET requests, generated by webkit during rendering, can be safely omitted if we just wanna grab text/links in the rendered html? For example, *.css?

Comment: If you're just trying to crawl web pages and don't want to render them, why render them with WebKit -- or any browser -- in the first place?

Comment: I mean that I don't care about images, fonts, but I want webkit to process client-side redirects, calls to Javascript code like `document.write` and so on.